# Increasing the server configured values for client timeouts

Tags: mysql

I am using log4j to maintain logs. so generally insert query gets executed to store logs details. i get the below exception only if the table contains more than 800 records. if i truncate table, insert query runs but fail to run if there are 800 + records

﻿com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet success
fully received from the server was 176,705,355 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 176,705,366 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.